# HTML CSS Image not loading in while migrating from one environment to another

Tags: deployment, migration, websphere

I am migrating my application on WebSphere from one environment to another environment the same .ear file is working fine in old environment(WebSphere) but HTML,CSS and Image not rendering properly in new environment(WebSphere).

i have verified configuration whatever i was knowing the configuration but issue still remain same.

Someone could please help in solving this WebSphere issue.

I have tried below points :

1. FileServingEnable=true
2. updating plugin config file.
3. Log is not giving any hint.
4. All versions are same.
5. httpd.config file comparison.
6. Image and data is present in folder and DB but not rendering in browser.

Comment: Do you receive the files at all?  "not rendering properly" could indicate you do not receive the file (so websphere config issue) or you receive the file but it is not properly interpreted by your browser.  If you do get the file, compare what you received (ex. with fiddler).  Same encoding?  Wrong line terminations (windows vs linux)?

Comment: I get response on image url like: RES_NOT_FOUND. Image is present in folder but not showing. It is a problem with data as well. I am using JSF prime faces for GUI page. But some of the data is loading and some of the data is not loading. Logs are not giving any hint here